# vector graphics mark-up language for maths diagrams

Tags: math, vector-graphics

I want to draw math diagrams, which I think falls in the category of vector graphics.

I used the Tex package [TikZ](http://www.texample.net/tikz/) for a long time, but the language is not clean enough for me and feels like a hack rather than a proper tool. For example there are so many backslashes e.g.

```
\foreach \x in {0,...,4} {
      \foreach \y in {\x,...,4} {
        \x --["\ifthenelse{\x=3 \OR \y=3 \OR \x=\y}{}{\x\y}",sloped] \y;
  }}
```

Then I tried [gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/), which seems to focus on plotting data rather than drawing diagrams. For example, to draw a simple circle, I need to `plot NaN` after `set object X circle ...`:

```
set xrange [-5:5]
set yrange [-5:5]
set object 1 circle at 0,0 size char 1 fillcolor rgb "black" fillstyle solid
plot NaN
```

I also tried [inkscape](https://inkscape.org/), but with its graphical interface, I hate looking for the correct button to click and prefer a markup-language type of tool.

I am going to try [asymptote](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/) now. Meanwhile, can anyone recommend a good vector graphics markup language that is convenient for creating math diagrams?

Answer (score 2):

## [Cairo](http://cairographics.org/)

Cairo is a library for creating 2D vector graphics. If you are already familiar with a well-known programming language, then Cairo most likely has a library for it. This means that you don't have to spend time learning a foreign syntax. It has bindings with [Python](http://cairographics.org/pycairo/), [Perl](http://www.cairographics.org/cairo-perl/), [C++](http://cairographics.org/cairomm/), [Java](http://www.cairographics.org/cairo-java/), and many others ([see complete list](http://www.cairographics.org/bindings/)). So you could use it with your preferred programming language. Features:

- Outputs in different formats, including `svg` for vector images
- Intuitive syntax
- Libraries for many common languages
- Is also integrated with some graphical toolkits (like [GTK+](http://www.gtk.org/) for Gimp)